# Add an item to audio CD auto play menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autoplay, audio-cd

I'm using Windows 10 OS. When I insert audio CD I have 2 additional items in Audio CD auto play menu. Applications Winamp and VLC have done something to the system so they would appear in Audio CD auto play menu. I would like to add third application. How can I do that?

For now, I don't need to send CD parameter so that app knows which drive to use. I only need to run an exe program.

[Autoplay menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu1Ya.png)

Comment: You can manage items and add in Control Panel, Auto Play. Have you tried this and can you add from the Auto Play menu?

Comment: Control Panel does not offer adding new items to Auto Play menu. It only offers selection (every time usage) of existing items along with "no action" and "ask every time".

What I need is to add new item.

Comment: Windows 10 will add hardware on its own and does not have a hardware wizard. Is the device you are trying to add Windows 10 compliant?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the answer on my own after digging through the registry.

This script will add Media Player Classic. I would just like to note that I don't know exactly how it works. This is mostly copy-paste from VLC.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MPC.CDAudio]
@="MPC CD Audio"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MPC.CDAudio\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc64.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MPC.CDAudio\shell]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MPC.CDAudio\shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MPC.CDAudio\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc64.exe\" /cd %1"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers\MPCPlayCDAudioOnArrival]
"Action"="Play audio CD"
"DefaultIcon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc64.exe\",0"
"InvokeProgID"="MPC.CDAudio"
"InvokeVerb"="Open"
"Provider"="Media Player Classic"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers\PlayCDAudioOnArrival]
"MPCPlayCDAudioOnArrival"=""
```

I would also like to note that open command is different for each program you register so the line @="\"C:\Program Files\MPC-HC\mpc-hc64.exe\" /cd %1" may differ.

From what I can tell parameters **Action** and **Provider** have arbitrary values. They only determine what you'll see in the Auto Play dialog.